# adding noise to prediction task

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, differential-privacy

Say that a teacher wishes to use a standard prediction task from Kaggle as a course assignment, and the idea is to have students submit their predictions, and award grades based on a test set (students are given the feature values for the test set). The teacher changes the names of the variables so that students are unable to directly google the variable names, but this is probably not sufficient to properly anonymise the data. What are some good ways to modify the  train/test data so that the task is still do-able, but the students are unable to cheat and submit existing predictions. For example, perhaps one could add noise to each variable, but how much noise can be added and what kind of noise maintains the structure of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You might try altering the target variable rather than the features. Each persons target variable might be offset by some secret constant, which preserves the relationships between variables and adjacent values but will ultimately change the parameter estimates (making some assumptions about model and data here).

Then, their submitted predictions will be specific to the secret offset that only you can decode